# git merge but only change lines untouched since 1st commit

Tags: git, merge

Consider this scenario with css files:

- File A was first versioned and has received changes from ~60 commits in 2 weeks (It was 14k lines, now it's 15k)
- File B was built upon the first version of File A and manually merged into File A a week after that.
- File C was built upon File B and is now also about 15k lines - but doesn't have any of the introduced changes to File A, except those from the original File B.

Having already tried manually merging these files twice without success - I'm always missing or inadvertently overriding something - I thought of automatically merging all lines that were unchanged since 1st commit (but were changed in File C). Then all unchanged lines since the B->A merge commit. And then manually parsing the left-overs, which should represent those 60 or so commits (made by multiple devs).

Is there a way to merge these files without overriding the patches and changes made to File A, in a way that all the new lines introduced in File C are added, but only lines that weren't changed since the selected commit (1st or merge) are merged?

Comment: If they are actually separate files under git, git won't merge them. I would recommend using a merge tool directly, such as `meld`, to handle this. http://meldmerge.org/. It also has features for automatically merging files which may help you (I have only used it for manual merges myself though, so I can't speak to the automerge quality.)

Comment: File C hasn't been versioned yet. Ideally I would only commit the final file to the repository, but I'm already considering other options. My two failed attempts to merge it were using  `meld` but it's just too many changes to keep track of.

Comment: Have you tried the automerge feature?

Comment: not yet. Will try :)

Comment: If files A,B, and C introduce changes to the same lines, you are going to have to manually merge no matter what. Any merge tool, including what `git` uses internally, will either overwrite or reject merges that introduce conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Find the SHA (B_MERGE_SHA)corresponding to the commit where File B was merged into A.

```
git checkout -b file_c_changes B_MERGE_SHA
```

overwrite File A with File C

```
cp "File C" "File A"
```

Add/Commit

```
git add "File A"
git commit -m "changes from file c"
```

checkout your original branch

```
git checkout ORIG_BRANCH
```

Merge in file C changes

```
git merge file_c_changes
```

Depending on your changes you may still have merge conflicts to resolve.